# Failed loading ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apache, ioncube

following situation:
I have Shopware 5.3.2 running with PHP version 7.1.8. For an installed plugin I need IonCube. I downloaded it and copied it to our server (RedHat 64bit).

I have the following settings on my server:

**PHP Version**

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 19:30:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

**extension_dir**

```
[root@vh1 modules]# php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

**Set include**

```
zend_extension=ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so
```

**Display PHP Version again**

```
[root@vh1 modules]# php -v
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: undefined symbol: zend_execute_ex
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 19:30:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I only get the error

```
Failed loading ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so:  ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's essential to match the major PHP version that you're using with the PHP version that modules are built for. In one error, you are using PHP 5.4 CLI whereas the Loader is for PHP 7.1. In another error you have the Loader for PHP 5.4 and PHP for something else. As a starting point to avoid unnecessary confusion, ensure that your CLI and web server PHP versions are the same - here I suspect that they are not. And then install the relevant Loader for your system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have php version 5.4 and your ioncube loader version is 7.1 you have to use the ioncube loader compatible with your php version 
I used this version and it works 
"ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so"

Comment: Their Loader was for *PHP version* 7.1 (it wasn't Loader version 7.1), but otherwise yes. All PHP modules need to be built to match the version and type of PHP being used, and on Windows, also match the compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with version 7.6. But in my case, it happened only on my Mac, and not on my Linux Ubuntu machine. And I was running PHP 7.6 in a Docker container on both machines.